# Can I use GNU parallel to group command arguments by a column value?

Tags: gnu-parallel

Consider the data from the [GNU parallel manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel.html)'s example for `--group-by`:

```bash
cat > table.csv <<"EOF"
UserID, Consumption
123,    1
123,    2
12-3,   1
221,    3
221,    1
2/21,   5
EOF
```

Is there a way to group records by one column and write all the values from another column in the group as command-line arguments?

This command doesn't group but otherwise gives me the output structure I want.

```bash
cat table.csv | parallel --colsep , --header : -kN1 echo UserID {1}  Consumption {2}
```

```
UserID 123 Consumption 1
UserID 123 Consumption 2
UserID 12-3 Consumption 1
UserID 221 Consumption 3
UserID 221 Consumption 1
UserID 2/21 Consumption 5
```

What command would give me output like this?

```
UserID 123 Consumption 1 2
UserID 12-3 Consumption 1
UserID 221 Consumption 3 1
UserID 2/21 Consumption 5
```

I also want to limit the number of "Consumption" values.

Say there were more than 4 in one of the groups.

```
cat > table.csv <<"EOF"
UserID, Consumption
123,    1
123,    2
123,    3
123,    4
123,    5
123,    6
123,    7
12-3,   1
221,    3
221,    1
2/21,   5
EOF
```

I want the command line to contain no more than 4 "Consumption" values.

```
UserID 123 Consumption 1 2 3 4
UserID 123 Consumption 5 6 7
UserID 12-3 Consumption 1
UserID 221 Consumption 3 1
UserID 2/21 Consumption 5
```

---

The manual shows how to use `--group-by` to select the correct groups.

```bash
cat table.csv | \
parallel --pipe --colsep , --header : --group-by UserID -kN1 wc
```

4 lines of `wc` output mean that it operates on 4 groups. The first group for example has 3 lines, 6 words, and 40 characters.

```
      3       6      40
      2       4      30
      3       6      40
      2       4      30
```

To make the group input clearer I swap `wc` for `cat`.

```bash
cat table.csv | \
parallel --pipe --colsep , --header : --group-by UserID -kN1 cat
```

The cat output shows that parallel passes the original input lines to the job and copies the header line as the first line of each group.

```
UserID, Consumption
123,    1
123,    2
UserID, Consumption
12-3,   1
UserID, Consumption
221,    3
221,    1
UserID, Consumption
2/21,   5
```

The problem is that `--group-by` makes Parallel use standard input instead of command-line arguments. I don't see a way around that.

Do I need to change the way I pass the arguments to GNU parallel? Do I need to use another tool to create the correct format before using GNU parallel to execute?

I'm using GNU parallel version 20231122.

Comment: Just FYI, you can end a line on `|` there is no need for `| \ `, the `|` alone is fine as the last character of the line. Any [control operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/22222) can be used as the last character of a line.

Comment: Thanks, @terdon. The GNU parallel manual uses that syntax and I copied it.

Comment: @terdon Not true if you use `csh`.

Comment: Ah! Really? That might explain why I see it so often. Thanks @OleTange, I was wondering why you would have done that and I suspected you knew something I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Bash you can do:

```
doit() { parallel --header : --colsep , -n4 echo UserID {1} Consumption {2} {4} {6} {8}; }
export -f doit
cat table.csv | parallel --pipe --colsep , --header : --group-by UserID -kN1 doit
```

I do not see you can do it in a single `parallel` instance. What you want is to mix `--pipe` and normal mode, and GNU Parallel can't really do that.

Comment: Thanks @OleTange. Is `-n` the number of lines and `{m}` the m'th argument across those lines? I'm not sure why `-n4` and Consumption goes up to `{8}`.

Comment: Yeah, I can see why that is confusing. The manual is clearly wrong (written before `--colsep`). `-n m` reads *m* records. These records are then split using `--colsep` which results in a number of replacement strings that each has a number. In our case we read 4 records (i.e. 4 lines), split these on , thus giving us 8 replacement strings.